# VS Emulator for Android has no internet connection

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, parallels, visual-studio-emulator

As the title says, my VS Android Emulator has no connection to the internet. In the Android screen, it says it's connected to WiFi, but browsing doesn't work.

Expect the problem is I am running Windows 10 in Parallels on my MacBook, but I don't know how to fix it. Windows "thinks" it's connected to ethernet.

My adapter settings in Windows look like this:

[image]

Hyper-V network settings for my emulator:

[image]

Network settings in Parallels is set to Bridged Network WIFI

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the device settings in your Android OS? Is the Airplane mode off, and mobile and wifi data turned on

Comment: I think with the help bridged networking you can solve this problem

Comment: are you able to connect from windows phone emulator ?

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling `Enable Virtual LAN Identification` from your Hyper-V Network settings screen. If that doesn't work, you may try changing the switch and VLAN IDs until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently announced a release of [VS for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/). That will be a far more user friendly option or even better go straight for the gold and use [Android studio 2](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). You really shouldn't have to run Parallels at all for what you are trying to do, and this is what is ultimately giving you problems in the first place. Even if you do solve this internet issue there will most likely be another issue that crops up and there are enough problems to deal with devving as it is.